# Can I use a web based IDE like Eclipse che for connecting to a server maintained by my university for python programming ?

Tags: web-ide

I want to edit the code through the IDEs text editor and debug and run it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Download Notepad ++ [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
Download WinScp [here](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Connect to your school's server with winscp, then navigate to whatever file you would like to edit. Right click and set the default editor to notepad ++. Now everytime you open any file, you can hot edit inside notepad ++.

I know i perhaps strayed from your full request, but i like this method for quickly updating code and testing on the server.